# visual basic adodc - category - multiple record with the same key

Tags: vb6

Well i'm trying to create a form in VB6 to control my database that was created by access, i did everything and everything went perfect,until i notice that if you enter the same "ID" i get an erreur from access that there is multiple Ids with the same number,since i activated the primary key in access so it doesn't allow that,so what i'm trying to do is when the user move from the Id cell to other cell,visual basic scan the id cell first and check if there is no other id with the same number,if it is i need visual basic to prompt me with msgbox that say's there is multiple id with the same number.
i hope that you understand what i'm trying to say i need a way to do it,just the way to follow.thanks 
* image :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqBpI.png

Answer (score 1):

Users do not enter Identity field values.

If this is about a DataGrid, you normally lock Identity columns as in:

```
With Adodc
    With New DbHandler 'A custom Class in the program.
        'This method will create a new database if we don't have one:
        Adodc.ConnectionString = .GetConnectionString(App.Path & "\" & DATABASE)
    End With
    'Use the table "Simple" here.
    .CommandType = adCmdTable 'Could be adCmdText.
    .RecordSource = "Simple"  'And then here a SELECT statement.
End With
With DataGrid
    Set .DataSource = Adodc

    'Lock and skip Column 0, which is a Counter/Identity field in this
    'database query resultset:
    .Columns(0).Locked = True
    .Col = 1
End With
```

It can also be useful to process this event:

```
Private Sub DataGrid_RowColChange(LastRow As Variant, ByVal LastCol As Integer)
    'This logic is meant to skip over our locked Column 0 in the user
    'interface when the user moves by cell-clicking or pressing cursor
    'keys.  Column 0 holds a Counter/Identity field in this query
    'resultset, so manual entry or editing would be a bad thing.
    '
    'Note:
    '
    '   Confusing, but here LastRow and LastCol parameters are really
    '   the "previous" cell coordinates and not the limits or counts
    '   of the rows and columns in the grid.
    With DataGrid
        If .Col = 0 Then
            If IsNull(LastRow) Then 'User moved down.
                .Col = 1
            ElseIf LastCol = .Col + 1 Then 'User moved left.
                If .Row = 0 Then
                    'No previous row to move to, so just move back!
                    .Col = LastCol
                Else
                    .Row = .Row - 1
                    .Col = .Columns.Count - 1
                End If
            Else 'User moved right.
                .Col = 1
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i uploaded a picture of the erreur.